# Grid element stacking in fixed area with fixed width and height elements

Tags: algorithm, grid, packing

I’m trying to figure out a solution of stacking or “packing” a series of rectangles and squares into blocks of `3x1` or `6x2` so that there isn’t a block with a protruding element and an uneven end. The width of the blocks can be a maximum of 3, before it has to break on another line. Image link below.

I have tried using 3 systems of measurements, Width + Height, Space (Num of single blocks an element occupies) + Width, Space + Height.

There are 5 possible elements that the grid can use. Image link below.

Using the S + H paradigm they are:

```
Name       |    Space x Height
Large           -   4 x 2  
Fullwidth       -   3 x 1
Horizontal      -   2 x 1
Vertical        -   2 x 2
Item(Single)    -   1 x 1
```

So far the logic has taken me to the situation that a block will always be either `3x1` or `6x2`. If the spaces taken exceed 3, it means the block must be at least 2 blocks tall, e.g if there is 2 elements with a total of 4 spaces the remaining elements must occupy only 2 spaces.

I've excluded the possibility of 9x3 for simplicity.

- Horizontal + Item

  Horizontal = 2 x 1
  2 spaces 1 Tall.
  Doesn’t fill out a row so we need another element.
  Item = 1 x 1
  2 + 1 = 3 Spaces
  1 = 1 = 1 Tall
  Horizontal + Item = 3x1.
- Item + Item + Item

  1x1 = 1 Space 1 Tall
  1x1 + 1x1 = 2 Spaces 1 Tall
  1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 = 3 Spaces 1 Tall
  Item + Item + Item = 3x1.
- Horizontal + Horizontal + Vertical

  2x1 = 2 Space 1 Tall
  2x1 + 2x1 = 4 Space 1 Tall
  Spaces are > 3, therefore the block must be 6x2 in the end. There are 4 spaces which means there must be elements added so they occupy 2 more spaces and be 2 tall.
  2x1 + 2x1 + 2x2 = 6 Spaces 2 Tall

I’m not sure if I’m close to a solution or way off.
The actual order of which elements are put in first doesn’t matter as I’m using an external library to place them in coherent blocks which handles that logic.
E.g `Horizontal + Horizontal + Vertical == Horizontal + Vertical + Horizontal`.
The logic will be written in PHP if that helps.

[***Image link here***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRbF5.png)